# Measuring how long a Key is pressed using p5.js and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to do some game development project with p5.js. Its really simple.
Essentially I need to be able to go ontop of an object on a map, and press the space bar. When I press the space bar, I am basically immobile. However, it should take a certain amount of seconds for me to retrieve the object. Now, I am wondering what the best way to do this be without changing the functionality. So, if I am on top of the object, I press space bar I am meant to ensure that the key remains pressed down for approximately 5 seconds. Which would mean I have to start the timer somewhere, but im still not sure how to approach this. Examples using function KeyPressed(), KeyIsDown(), KeyReleased() would be helpful. Thank you

Edit:
So currently, I have been thinking of using a counter (not that effective at all but it is what it is), but then I am thinking instead of looking at having a global timer.

Example Code:

`

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let PickUpRate = 0
  push()
  let x = 100
  let y = 100
  let size = 64
  fill(100,63)
  //base
  rect(x-size/2, y-size/2-20,size,10);
  //health
  fill(0,220,0)
  rect(x-size/2, y-size/2-20,size*abs(PickUpRate)/100,10);
  pop()
}

function keyPressed(event){
  console.log(event.timeStamp)
}
function keyReleased(event){
  console.log(event.timeStamp)
}
```

`

https://editor.p5js.org/

This is what I have to work with so far, but I have to also increment my bar somehow using the timestamp? How should this be done?

Comment: KeyPressed - take timestamp, KeyReleased take timestamp and check if difference is greater than amount needed to pickup. Otherwise you could use KeyIsDown to perform this check and use the data from it to have a progressbar updating on each tick. Something along these lines. The "best" approach always depends on your preferred goal/usage/display of the feature needed.

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyReleased

Comment: You need to at least make an attempt to code a solution and if you cannot make it work post your code.

Comment: i realise all of this, but I also need to be able to USE the timestamp or some sort of timer thing to update the progress bar.

Comment: @D.Schaller Would timestamps help me update a progress bar during the moment though

Comment: Of course. If you know when the key was pressed and you know the current time, you know how long it’s been down.

Comment: @rayhatfield the bar needs to be filled almost iteratively, so i dont know how that can be achieved

Comment: With a [timeout or interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals)?

Comment: @rayhatfield So as soon someones presses a space bar when they are at a certain location, the bar should appear. It takes 5 seconds to retrieve that object so. The bar is going to be out of 100. So every 50 milliseconds, the bar should be filling up slowly for as long as the person presses the spacebar on that location.

Comment: So, again, use a [timeout or interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals) to update the bar.

Comment: @Steveit Simple math at this point. You almost got there, but you focused on the wrong value. It doesn't matter if it takes 50ms to fill one percent, since you shouldn't bottleneck your application by limiting the time to tick. What you want to figure out on each tick, is how many percent of 5s, you are at. And BAM, thats your progress bar value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use timestamps and/or application time to evaluate if a certain progress has been made.

I created a little snippet to demonstrate the thought on how to do it.
This might not be the best solution but it should give you a hint in the right direction.

On KeyPressed -> Get Time.

While KeyIsDown -> Check whether the time holding the Button is equal to timeToPickUp, if not calculate progress as percent and update the progress bar.

As soon as the value reaches/exceeds 100, perform action and stop drawing the progress bar.

I never worked with p5js before, therefore the code is certainly not "production ready", but you get the idea.

```js
let timeToPickUp = 5000; //ms of time to pick up
let startOfPickUp = 0; // var to save timeStamp to
let progress = 0; // var to save progress value


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let PickUpRate = 0
  push()
  let x = 100
  let y = 100
  let size = 64
  fill(100,63)
  //base
  rect(x-size/2, y-size/2-20,size,10);
  //health
  fill(0,220,0)
  rect(x-size/2, y-size/2-20,size*abs(PickUpRate)/100,10);
  pop()
  
  if(keyIsDown(32)) { // Check if spacebar is pressed
    if(startOfPickUp > 0 && progress < 100) { // Don't draw if invalid
      progress = (millis() - startOfPickUp) / timeToPickUp * 100; //get progress
      
      //draw progress
      fill(255,0,0)
      rect(10, 350, progress, 25)
      
      if(progress >= 100) {
        console.log('do whatever is supposed to happen automatically');
      }
    }
  }
}

function keyPressed(event){
  startOfPickUp = millis() // get start
}
function keyReleased(event){
  startOfPickUp = 0; // remove values when released
  progress = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick proof of concept implementation using setTimeout:

```js
// class to encapsulate the progress tracking and meter updating
class Progress {
  constructor(elem, duration = 2000, updateInterval = 50) {
    // the meter DOM element
    this.elem = elem;
    
    // the currently active timeout id
    this.timeoutId = null;
    
    // when progress tracking started
    this.startTime = null;
    
    // how long it takes to complete
    this.duration = duration;
    
    // how frequently to update the meter
    this.updateInterval = updateInterval;
  }
  
  start() {
    if (this.startTime) {
      // already running
      return;
    }
    
    // track when it started
    this.startTime = Date.now();
    
    // start updating
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.update(), this.updateInterval);
  }
  
  stop() {
    // cancel the timeout if it exists
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    
    // reset the meter css
    this.elem.style.setProperty('--complete', '0%');
    this.elem.classList.remove('complete');
    
    // clear our internal variables
    this.timeoutId = null;
    this.startTime = null;
  }
  
  update() {
    // compute the percentage complete based on start time and current time, and cap it at 100%
    const percentComplete = Math.min((Date.now() - this.startTime ?? Date.now()) / this.duration, 1) * 100;
    
    // set the css property used to do the fill
    this.elem.style.setProperty('--complete', `${percentComplete}%`);
    
    if (percentComplete >= 100) {
      // if we're at 100%, add the 'complete' class to the meter
      this.elem.classList.add('complete');
    }
    else {
      // otherwise set up the next update
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.update(), this.updateInterval);
    }
  }
}

// create an instance of Progress for our meter element
const progress = new Progress(document.getElementById('meter'));

// start on keydown
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  progress.start();
})

// stop on keyup
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  progress.stop();
})
```

```css
#meter {
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  
  /* use a custom property 'complete' to fill the appropriate amount of the bar */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--fillColor, limegreen) var(--complete, 0%), #eee var(--complete, 0%) 100%);
}

/* class and animation for flashing the box shadow upon completion */
.complete {
  animation: .1s ready infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes ready {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 4px red;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="meter"></div>
```